# groupBy multiple keys in scala

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe similar to following:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq((100, 1, 1), (100, 1,2), (100, 2,3), (200, 1,1), (200, 2,3), (200, 2, 2), (200, 3, 1), (200, 3,2), (300, 1,1), (300,1,2), (300, 2,5), (400, 1, 6))).toDF("_c0", "_c1", "_c2")

+---+---+--------------------+
|_c0|_c1|                 _c2|
+---+---+--------------------+
|100|  1|1                   |
|100|  1|2                   |
|100|  2|3                   |
|200|  1|1                   |
|200|  2|3                   |
|200|  2|2                   |
|200|  3|1                   |
|200|  3|2                   |
|300|  1|1                   |
|300|  1|2                   |
|300|  2|5                   |
|400|  1|6                   |
```

I need to groupBy _c0 and _c1 and get some rdd like this:

```
res9: Array[Array[Array[Int]]] = Array(Array(Array(1, 2), Array(3)), Array(Array(1), Array(3, 2), Array(1, 2)), Array(Array(1, 2), Array(5)), Array(Array(6)))
```

It is an array of array, I am new in scala. Please try to help

Comment: Can you explain more about your output?

Comment: I need to do groupBy of _c0 and _c1. So lets say, first one is 100, if we are doing a groupby of _c1, I am expecting an array of array. ie, [[1,2], [3]] for _c0==100

Comment: How you are generating this output? `res9: Array[Array[Array[Int]]] = Array(Array(Array(1, 2), Array(3)), Array(Array(1), Array(3, 2), Array(1, 2)), Array(Array(1, 2), Array(5)), Array(Array(6)))
`

Comment: Say, _c0 is 100,


Groupby of _c1 will have 2 groups. so for that [[1,2], [3]]
say _c1 is 200, _c1 has 1,2 and 3, ie, 3 groups [[1], [3,2], [1,2]]

Comment: still confused?

Comment: yes still confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first `groupBy` `_c0` and `_c1` together and then `groupBy` only `_c1` to get your desired result. Below is the code for same.

```
//first group by "_c0" and "_c1"
val res = df.groupBy("_c0", "_c1").agg(collect_list("_c2").as("_c2"))
  //group by "_c0"
  .groupBy("_c0").agg(collect_list("_c2").as("_c2"))
  .select("_c2")

res.show(false)

//output
//+---------------------------------------------------------+
//|_c2                                                      |
//+---------------------------------------------------------+
//|[WrappedArray(1, 2), WrappedArray(5)]                    |
//|[WrappedArray(1, 2), WrappedArray(3)]                    |
//|[WrappedArray(6)]                                        |
//|[WrappedArray(3, 2), WrappedArray(1, 2), WrappedArray(1)]|
//+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

For converting this to `RDD` use `.rdd` to the resulting `dataframe`.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray
val rdd = res.rdd.map(x => x.get(0)
  .asInstanceOf[WrappedArray[WrappedArray[Int]]].array.map(x => x.toArray))

//to get the content or rdd(Don't use it if data is too big)
rdd.collect()
//output
//Array(Array(Array(1, 2), Array(5)), Array(Array(1, 2), Array(3)), Array(Array(6)), Array(Array(3, 2), Array(1, 2), Array(1)))
```